# Get Job Name from "program_name" in sp_whoisactive results

Tags: sql-server

I'm logging the output of `sp_whoisactive` to a table to help identify problems I need to look into further.

I'm noticing most of my high utilization queries are coming from SQLAgent Jobs, and within the "`Program_Name`" column, it only gives me "`SQLAgent - TSQL Job Step (Job 0xFA25C66E3D1.... : Step 7)`" as an example.

How can I get back the actual job name bearing in mind that I can't run `sp_who` or similar to check as this is previous executions.

Comment: select * from msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps

Comment: Hi @MitchWheat, there no field that matches in there. This isn't a GUID I don't believe.

Comment: I found that too, but notice the "from" clause. It's taking it from a trace file and it doesn't match up with the job_id in my sysjobs table. Old article and I assume its no longer current as none of my job_ids start with FA25

Answer (score 1):

The below will give you queries that are sorted by blocking victim, as well as JobName as requested.

```
    SELECT  er.session_id as [Spid]
     ,er.percent_complete
    ,DB_NAME(er.database_id) as [Database]
    ,CASE WHEN er.blocking_session_id=er.session_id THEN 0 ELSE er.blocking_session_id END Blocker
    ,Mem.used_memory_kb
    ,er.wait_time
    ,Mem.granted_memory_kb
    ,ES.nt_user_name
    ,er.status as [Status]
    ,er.wait_type as [Wait]        
    ,ES.program_name
    ,J.Name as JobName
    ,ES.host_name
    ,ES.nt_domain
    ,er.start_time
    ,CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, er.start_time, GETDATE()), 0), 108) TotalTime
    ,cast(qp.query_plan as XML) plans
    ,SUBSTRING(qt.text, er.statement_start_offset / 2,2000) [running Query]
    ,qt.text  [Parent Query]
    FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests er
    inner JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ES ON er.session_id = ES.session_id
    outer APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) AS qt
    outer apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(er.plan_handle) qp
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants Mem ON er.session_id = Mem.session_id
    Left join msdb.dbo.sysjobs J on es.program_name  like '%'+cast(right(j.job_id,12)as varchar(12)) +'%'
    WHERE   ES.program_name <>'Microsoft® Windows® Operating System'        
    ORDER BY
    4  DESC ,
    1  asc
```